# How to write multiple COUNT(*) subqueries in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count, subquery

How to write subqueries in Rails like this?:

```
select
    m.field1,
    m.field2,
    (select count(*) from details1 d1 where d1.id=m.field3) as count1,
    (select count(*) from details2 d2 where d2.id=m.field4) as count2,
    (select count(*) from details3 d3 where d3.id=m.field5) as count3
from
    master m
```

Database server is PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Master < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "master"
end
masters = Master.select(%Q"master.field1, master.field2,
(select count(*) from details1 d1 where d1.id=m.field3) as count1,
(select count(*) from details2 d2 where d2.id=m.field4) as count2,
(select count(*) from details3 d3 where d3.id=m.field5) as count3").all
```

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `set_table_name' for Master:Class (Rails 3.2.3)

Comment: It seems that the select itself is able to accept an arbitrary SQL string. Thank you for the clue. A bookmark for myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374105/using-raw-sql-queries-in-rails-3-application

Comment: Should have included inheritance from AR.  I'll edit my answer.